# Oracle on Solaris 10 : 15min TCP Timeout

Tags: solaris, oracle, tcp

I have Oracle10g running on Solaris 10. The configuration of the OS is standard, and there is a packet filter firewall running on the server.

When I run a long query using sqldeveloper, the server reset the connection after 15 minutes of inactivity.

The timeline is:

1. client establishes the connection to server port 1521, no ssl
2. server accept and receives the query from the client. the last packet exchanged is a TCP ACK from the server to the client
3. ... 15 minutes (to the second) pass
4. server send a RST packet to the client, and nothing else is exchanged between the hosts afterward

I couldn't find any timeout parameter for TNS listener, so I'm guessing it might be a solaris or packet filter issue ?

Comment: Do you have packet captures from both the client and server showing that reset?

Comment: nope, from the client only

Comment: Then it could be some firewall in between the two systems too.

Comment: Correct, that's actually a sonicwall tcp timeout. Found the parameter, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was located in a border firewall, a sonicwall, that had a default tcp timeout set at 15 minutes.

Not a solaris or oracle problem then.